# Execute code using annotations before the method is executed

Tags: java, annotations

I want run some code before a method is executed at run-time and I want to achieve it using annotation. I have an annotation `@SetValues`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface SetValues
{}
```

I am new to annotations and have couple of questions

1. How can I have some code being executed when this annotation is attached to a method
2. How can i have the code associated with the annotation run before a method execution?

Comment: Define "before a method is executed". At compile time, at runtime? Also are you aware that adding an annotation will itself do absolutely nothing during execution of the code? Only code (which you have to write) that looks via reflection at annotated classes can do things with them. Maybe that's what you mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ

Comment: @zapl , Yes I want to add code but not sure how to do that. Also what should I do so that it gets executed before the method execution at run time

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways this can be done:

1. Aspect oriented programming was already mentioned, AspectJ is a standard here.
2. You can write a piece of code yourself that does a similar thing. In this case you might want to wrap all (only some?) objects of interfaces which have those annotated methods in a proxy (have a look at [java.lang.reflect.proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)) which executes the code you want before the method itself is called (have a look at [java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html)). Combine this with [Method.getDeclaredAnnotations()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations--) and you can probably build the thing you want.

But I'm not quite sure as to what you exactly it is you want. The name "SetValues" seems to imply that you want to change the value of certain fields (and maybe restore them after the execution of the method). You have to realise that the InvocationHandler can only do so much. It cannot and should not break encapsulation for example (at least not any more so than any other piece of code can do with the help of reflection).
Another point to consider with such a feature is that it may interact very badly with concurrent execution of such methods when the InvocationHandler attempts to change values that both methods need.